# Intuition for Basis of a Field Extension

Tags: galois-theory

So from my understanding, when we are computing the basis for an extension of a field ( for example the degree of $\left[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}]:\mathbb{Q} \right]$) we are considering $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space in which the scalars are elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. In extending $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt[]{2}$, we are looking to find a basis in which:

1) We can produce any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and any multiple of $\sqrt[]{2}$

2) The set is closed under multiplication and addition of the the elements produced by linear combinations of $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[]{2}$

So for me it is obvious that the basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}]/\mathbb{Q}$ is $\langle 1, \sqrt[]{2} \rangle$. But when we extend the same field by another element, like $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and others, or make the scalar field itself an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ I am having a little trouble conceptualizing a general approach for this basis.

My confusion comes from ensuring closure when the scalar field contains an element of the extension i.e. $\left[\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}]: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}] \right]$.

So in this instance I know that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a member of the basis for the extension since it is a scalar and can be produced by multiplying $1$ by $\sqrt[3]{2}$. I know that since $\sqrt[]{2}$ is not a scalar it is required to belong to the basis, and so our basis definitely contains $1$ and $\sqrt[]{2}$.

Since the extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ contains all the powers of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, is the basis just $\langle1,\sqrt[]{2} \rangle$? And for any extension for $\mathbb{Q}[a_1,..., a_n]/\mathbb{Q}[a_1,... a_{i-1},a_{i+1}, ... a_n]$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ is the degree just equal to $\mathbb{Q}[a_i]$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are finding a basis for the extension as a vector space, then you don't consider multiplication when generating the field extension.  Thus $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]/\mathbb{Q}$ would have a basis of $1$, $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$.

For the last question, it depends on what the $a_i$ are.  If $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_2=\sqrt[4]{2}$, then $[\mathbb{Q}[a_1,a_2]:\mathbb{Q}[a_1]]=2$, but $[\mathbb{Q}[a_2]:\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

Comment: But in the instance of extension by two elements we do though correct? Given that you would want to ensure that elements of the form $a+b \sqrt[]{2}$ can be multiplied by $c+d \sqrt[3]{2}$ and still remain in the field. So you just have to cover all possible combinations of the powers of the elements you're extending the field by?

Comment: @SirJective Yes, you'd have $\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\sqrt{2}(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$, etc.

Comment: What about the last question that I asked?

Comment: @SirJective I edited the post.